# How do I get multiple values of of checked checkboxes at once with/without using foreach? Php

Tags: php, checkbox

What I have here is a checkbox of days from Monday - Friday.

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb_day[]" id="cb_day" value="Monday">Monday     
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb_day[]" id="cb_day" value="Tuesday">Tuesday
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb_day[]" id="cb_day" value="Wednesday">Wednesday
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb_day[]" id="cb_day" value="Thursday">Thursday
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb_day[]" id="cb_day" value="Friday">Friday 
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb_day[]" id="cb_day" value="Saturday">Saturday
```

I get it that if you wanted to post values all checked checkboxes, use foreach. But that just selects the latest value.

```
  foreach($_POST['cb_day'] as $selected{
  echo "<p>" . $selected . "</p>";
  }else
  echo "Please select at least one option.";
  }
```

What I wanted to ask is: If I selected multiple values(ex. monday and tuesday), how should I code those multiple values as a single value(in this case: MT)?

EX: If I wanted to add another schedule

```
  [ ]monday         [/]thursday
  [/]tuesday        [ ]friday
  [ ]wednesday      [ ]saturday
  -----------------------------
  [/]monday         [/]thursday
  [ ]tuesday        [ ]friday
  [ ]wednesday      [ ]saturday
```

So for example I chose those, the output should be like this:

```
  TTH
  MTH
```

But the output in my code only showed the latest which is just:

```
  MTH
```

How do I catch those checked checkboxes and post it as a single value without losing the earlier values?

(Sorry for lengthy explanation. First time in stackoverflow.)

Comment: what is `TTH` & `MTH` ?

Comment: Consider giving your checkboxes different id, and keeping them in a div. Then you go through all child elements in the div.

Comment: Tuesday Thursday - TTH

Comment: Monday Thursday - MTh

Comment: Inside the example of foreach above. I tried this:

'if ($selected === 'Monday' || $selected === 'Thursday'){ //code }' 

but that just reads 'monday' OR 'thursday'. I know 'monday' AND 'thursday' wouldn't work since its inside a foreach statement.

Answer (score 0):

It may seem early but this codes look promising:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if(!empty($_POST['cb_day'])) {
    $checked_count = count($_POST['cb_day']);
    if ($checked_count == '1'){
          echo "You have selected ".$checked_count." day: <br/>";
          //echo codes
    }else if ($checked_count > '1'){
    echo "You have selected " . $checked_count . " days";        
    $day_values = $_POST['cb_day'];
    sort($day_values);
    $tday_value = implode($day_values);
    echo "<p>" . $tday_value . "</p>";
    }
  }
}
```

If I change the value of my checkboxes to their initials(Monday = M, Tuesday = T)
Monday and Tuesday will be imploded as:

```
  MT
```